# How to get correct file extension when you know content-type

Tags: c#, file, content-type

I have a byte[] containing data for a file. Array can contain data for several different filetypes like xml, jpg, html, csv, etc.

I need to save that file in disk.

I'm looking for a c# code to find out proper file extension when you know content-type, but aren't sure for the file extension?

Comment: Here is the opposite of what you are asking for: https://gist.github.com/958009  ---- you should be able to reverse it pretty easily, it's at least a decent starting point.

Comment: http://cyotek.com/article/display/mime-types-and-file-extensions has a snippet which is easier to use than reversing @Matt's snippet.

Comment: @Matt Greer- That's not very helpful unless the OP plans to loop through every extension in HKCR. *Edit* I didn't see @Aurojit's comment, that's a better way. :) @Clack: Are there a finite number of content types or are they unknown at compile time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://cyotek.com/article/display/mime-types-and-file-extensions has a snippet for doing this, essentially looking up the extension in the registry under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\<mime type>`

Comment: This does, of course, mean that the computer the code is running on needs to know that mime-type/extension information but that should be ok.

Comment: Well, it _might_ be ok, but it might well not be ok. If you're a web server dealing with application-specific files, e.g. Excel, you may well have a content type that's not installed on the web server

Answer (score 2):

maybe this converter code can help:

```
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> MimeTypeToExtension = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ExtensionToMimeType = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    public static string ConvertMimeTypeToExtension(string mimeType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mimeType))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mimeType");

        string key = string.Format(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\{0}", mimeType);
        string result;
        if (MimeTypeToExtension.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            return result;

        RegistryKey regKey;
        object value;

        regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key, false);
        value = regKey != null ? regKey.GetValue("Extension", null) : null;
        result = value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;

        MimeTypeToExtension[key] = result;
        return result;
    }

    public static string ConvertExtensionToMimeType(string extension)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extension))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("extension");

        if (!extension.StartsWith("."))
            extension = "." + extension;

        string result;
        if (ExtensionToMimeType.TryGetValue(extension, out result))
            return result;

        RegistryKey regKey;
        object value;

        regKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension, false);
        value = regKey != null ? regKey.GetValue("Content Type", null) : null;
        result = value != null ? value.ToString() : string.Empty;

        ExtensionToMimeType[extension] = result;
        return result;
    }
```

origin of the idea comes from here:
[Snippet: Mime types and file extensions](http://cyotek.com/blog/mime-types-and-file-extensions)