# Is there a way to get an extension for a given content type?

Tags: c#, content-type

Is there a way to do the inverse of this?

[content type by extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910097/content-type-by-extension/1910179#1910179)

I have a `WebResponse` which has a content type and I need to cache the response with the appropriate extension.

image/png => .png

image/jpg => .jpg

Comment: What if there's more than one extension that corresponds to a MIME type? Worse, what if one extension corresponds to different MIME types?

Comment: The later is not a problem at all.  The former is just an extension of my primary problem.  I have to cache WHATEVER I'm given in a usable format (i.e. with the appropriate extension).  I am trying to avoid using a switch statement as that is guaranteed to leave things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has a MIME-type database in the Registry. Internet Explorer uses this database to select the default extension for downloads in its `Save As` dialog.

The machine-level database is under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MIME\Database`, with user-specific overrides under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\MIME\DataBase`. Windows merges these trees and exposes the result under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\DataBase`.

The Content-Type mappings are in a tree located under the `Content Type` subkey; for example, the `audio/mp3` type is located at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\audio/mp3
```

The default file extension, including the leading period character, is in the `Extension` named value.

Since [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904308/how-to-get-correct-file-extension-when-you-know-content-type) already contains a snippet to do this I won't reinvent the wheel here :-)