# What is the correct value for the accept attribute in HTML input tag to show .p7m files?

Tags: html, firefox, input, attributes, mime-types

I have the following problem, I want to create a HTML input field, where a user can upload a .p7m file and if he clicks on it, he should only see files of that type, but it does not work properly.
To change the displayed files, I usually change the "accept" attribute as seen in the example below.

```html
<input class="uploadFile" name="file" type="file" id="file" placeholder="Your P7M..." accept="application/pkcs7-mime" >
```

What bothers me, is that I don't get the correct files shown for the values I choose in Firefox 60.4.0esr (64-Bit) on Windows 10:

- "application/pkcs7-mime" -> Only shows .p7c Files
- "application/x-pkcs7-mime" -> Shows all files

Google Chrome shows .p7m files as well on the same machine.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OS may be responsible for this. Which do you use? Do other browser work? The MIME types you tried seem correct...

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: In Google Chrome, with the code snipped above, I can see .p7m and .p7c files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers use a combination of their own data and the OS data for MIME type <-> file extension mapping.

Chrome apparently has [hardcoded mappings for "application/pkcs7-mime"](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/mime_util.cc?l=186&rcl=64d095840549d8053f55c9d3c32054dd119a168d), which [are used when the OS doesn't provide info on the MIME type](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/mime_util.cc?l=108&rcl=64d095840549d8053f55c9d3c32054dd119a168d).

Firefox does not, so I think in your case it shows the extensions configured in the OS. (If anyone's curious, here's the [entry point](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/325c1a707819602feff736f129cb36055ba6d94f/dom/html/HTMLInputElement.cpp#6848), the [hardcoded values](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/content/filepicker.properties) and the [code that queries the OS on Windows](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/325c1a707819602feff736f129cb36055ba6d94f/uriloader/exthandler/win/nsOSHelperAppService.cpp#51).) Check what's in [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pkcs7-mime`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7895371/1026) on your system.

I don't think you can control this from a web page.