# How to handle URL having no specific suffix

Tags: c#

My Code for Downloader uses two textboxes :

1. Two get user URL
2. To specify the drive

   ```
    private void downloadbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

       WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

       //Declarations for string objects
       string downloadURL, path;
       //raw URL taken from user
      downloadURL =  this.downloadURL.Text;

      path = savePath.Text;



       Uri tmp = new Uri(downloadURL);
      string EndPathFileName = tmp.Segments.Last();
      path = path + @"\" + EndPathFileName;

      //downloads file using async method

      myWebClient.DownloadFileAsync(tmp, savePath.Text);
     }
   ```

The issue arises when i use URL of type:
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1coxfe_aryan-khan-tera-pyar-official-music-video-hd_music
 which didn't have any suffix i.e. mp3,mp4 etc.
Here it downloads an icon of zero data in the winkle of eye as compared to url having *.mp3/4 etc

Any suggestions please

Comment: In these cases you would need to examine the mime type in the `Content-Type` header, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904308/how-to-get-correct-file-extension-when-you-know-content-type

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Content-Type header not the URL to know the type of file. You can read the content-type like this

```
string type = client.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
```

Comment: It's returning NullReferenceException even for URL's that worked for me previously

Comment: Is ResponseHeaders null or the type variable is null?

Comment: NullReferenceException is thrown for  WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;

Comment: So "myWebClient" is null for some reason?

Comment: Is "myWebClient" null and if yes why?