# Send multiple files under folder as an email attachment

Tags: c#, zip, email-attachments, memorystream, dotnetzip

I want to send zip file as an attachment in mail folder wise.This is my folder structure:

```
Document  => Part1 =>all files.
          => Part2 =>all files.
```

In this above way i want to create a zip file name **ATTachment** in that my **Document** folder will there which will contain folder **Part1** and **Part2**.

This is my code:

```
string item1="1,2"; //document ids
string item2="3,4";//document ids
MemoryStream memoryStreamOfFile = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    foreach (var item in item1.Split(','))
    {
          var File1 = new FileDataResult();
          File1  = GetData(item);
          stream.Write(File1.FileData.ToArray(), 0,File1.FileData.Length);
          stream.Position = 0;
          zip.AddEntry(File1.FileData.FileName, stream);
    } 
   foreach (var item in item2.Split(','))
    {
         var File1 = new FileDataResult();
          File1  = GetData(item);
          stream.Write(File1.FileData.ToArray(), 0,File1.FileData.Length);
          stream.Position = 0;
          zip.AddEntry(File1.FileData.FileName, stream);
    } 
     zip.Save(memoryStreamOfFile);
     memoryStreamOfFile.Position = 0;
     sendmail.SendMail(string From, string To, string Subject, string Body,MemoryStream stream);

 mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream,"ATTachment.zip",MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip));


public static FileDataResult GetData(string DocID)
{
   //Database code to fetch binary data from database
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
               while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader[0] == null)
                    return null;
                byte[] raw = (byte[])reader[0]; 
                File.FileData = raw;
                File.FileName = reader[1].ToString();
                reader.Close();
                return File;
            }
}



public class FileDataResult
    {
        public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Email is going successfully but the problem is when i am extracting zip file and then i am not getting any data in the file.for eg In case of image i am not getting image.

[image]

Comment: Where are the file extensions? You get the image. It is just, the OS does not know that it is an image. Try to specify file extensions like "Abc" + item + ".tiff"

Comment: But how to create the structure which i have specified in my question

Comment: What is the type of "zip"? If it is IonicZip, [here is the method you should use](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/e96683da-04b7-faef-cca3-e73233b76af0.htm). If it is not, I am sure there is a similar method to add a directory.

Comment: @OguzOzgul:I am using Dotnetzip

Comment: @OguzOzgul:I have extension like this:Image/jpeg.So now how to specify this in "Abc" + item + ".tiff" ??

Comment: It has a method with the same name. ZipEntry.CreateDirectoryByName(string); This will return another ZipEntry which you can use to add files to the new folder.

Comment: @OguzOzgul:It would be more better if you post some solution as it would really help me

Comment: For the latter, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904308/how-to-get-correct-file-extension-when-you-know-content-type)

Comment: My IPhone does not have Visual Studio, sorry. I documented everything you need.

Comment: @OguzOzgul:Now i am doing this: zip.AddEntry(File.FileName, stream);here File.FileName is like abc.png but still i am not getting image

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows;

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
    {
        zip.AddFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file));
    }
    zip.Save("test.zip"));
}
```

Comment: I have binary data saved in my database and so i am fetching binary data from database by doc id and creating zip files from it